# years difference date from field php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make the form that does not accept a member below 20 years old so I'm trying to do this code but it gives me an error

```
$dob=$_POST["date"];            
$today =date_create(date('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $db=create_date(date($dob));
        $diff=date_diff($db,$today,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First here is the `date_create` function definition :

```
DateTime date_create ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

As you can see, the default time is now, so you can save up a few characters.
Then, if `$dob` is in a valid format (see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), here is your solution:

```
$today = date_create();
$db = date_create($dob);
$diff = date_diff($db, $today, true);
```

Happy coding!